# json.dump() gives me "TypeError: keys must be a string"

Tags: python, json

I have some very simple code that takes a dictionary with a tuple as a key and turns it into json:

```
In [11]:

import simplejson as json
In [12]:

data = {('category1', 'category2'): 4}
In [13]:

json.dumps(data)
```

However, running the code gives me:

```
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

I have tried str()'ing the keys and everything else I can find, but without luck.

Comment: Do you know the JSON format? It doesn't allow keys like `('category1', 'category2')` - heck, it doesn't have tuples at all. You'll have to reorganize your data.

Comment: You may hack it by creating string from the tuple like {"category1#category2":4}. JSON itself doesn't work with tuples as keys.

Answer (score 9):

The error seems pretty clear: Your keys must be strings.

If I take the example from your question and `str()`-ify the keys:

```
>>> data = {str(('category1', 'category2')): 4}
```

It works just fine:

```
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"(\'category1\', \'category2\')": 4}'
```

Having said that, in your position I would consider making your keys more readable.  Possibly something like:

```
>>> data = dict((':'.join(k), v) for k,v in data.items())
```

This turns a key like `('category1', 'category2')` into `category1:category2`,

Comment: It would be nice if this answer could explain how to restore the original object. `json` serialization is a two-way operation... It is not enough to do `dumps`, one also has to know how to `loads`.

Comment: I'm not sure: the question isn't really clear about what data structure is actually required. Is the string-ified key sufficient? Then one can simply call `loads` on the JSON data and be done with it. If the data structure *requires* tuples as key, then the solution is going to look different. That said, if you have particular questions around de-serializing JSON, feel free to open a new question and we'd be happy to help out.

Answer (score 4):

I know that [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states

> Flat is better than nested.

However, for my context, I had some levels of nested dicts. So I recursively treated it:

```python
import json

def key_to_json(data):
    if data is None or isinstance(data, (bool, int, str)):
        return data
    if isinstance(data, (tuple, frozenset)):
        return str(data)
    raise TypeError

def to_json(data):
    if data is None or isinstance(data, (bool, int, tuple, range, str, list)):
        return data
    if isinstance(data, (set, frozenset)):
        return sorted(data)
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {key_to_json(key): to_json(data[key]) for key in data}
    raise TypeError

data = {('category1', 'category2'): {frozenset(['cat1', 'cat2']): 1212}}
json.dumps(to_json(data))
# '{"(\'category1\', \'category2\')": {"frozenset({\'cat2\', \'cat1\'})": 1212}}'
```

Adjust this code to match your context.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the below approach.
Make the key of your dictionary a string rather than tuple before conversion to json. When converting json back to dictionary, convert back into list/tuple.

```
data  =['category1', 'category2']
data_map = {}
data_map[','.join(data)]= 4
json.dumps(data_map)
```

Do not forget to convert back the string to list once you convert read the json to dictionary

Comment: How to convert string to tuple  when we read the json file?

Answer (score 2):

As @starriet said, if your goal is to serialize and then deserialize without data loss then you should look at [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

However, if you just wanna print things for debugging/human readability then checkout the `stringify` method:

```py
import json
import numpy as np
from collections.abc import Iterable

encode = json.JSONEncoder().encode


def cast_key(key):
    "Cast dictionary key"
    try:
        encode({key: 123})
        return key
    except:
        pass

    if isinstance(key, tuple):
        return encode(key)

    return str(key)


def cast_value(value):
    "Cast dictionary value"
    try:
        encode(value)
        return value
    except TypeError:
        pass

    try:
        if np.issubdtype(value, np.integer):
            return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return str(value)


def coerce_types(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, dict):
        obj = {}
        for k, v in arg.items():
            k = cast_key(k)
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                v = coerce_types(v)
            else:
                v = cast_value(v)
            obj[k] = v
        return obj
    elif isinstance(arg, Iterable):
        return [coerce_types(e) for e in arg]
    else:
        return cast_value(arg)


def stringify(obj):
    # First try default serializer
    try:
        return json.dumps(obj)
    except TypeError:
        pass

    # Default failed, so we coerce types and try again
    obj_prep = coerce_types(obj)
    return json.dumps(obj_prep)
```

### PyTest

```py
import numpy as np
from stringify import stringify


def test_simple_object():
    input = {'foo': 'bar'}
    expected = '{"foo": "bar"}'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual


def test_nested_object():
    input = {'foo': {'child': 'bar'}, 'age': 20}
    expected = '{"foo": {"child": "bar"}, "age": 20}'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual


def test_numpy_value_int():
    input = {'foo': np.int64(123)}
    expected = '{"foo": 123}'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual


def test_numpy_value_float():
    input = {'foo': np.float64(123.456)}
    expected = '{"foo": 123.456}'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual


def test_numpy_key():
    input = {np.int64(123): 'foo'}
    expected = '{"123": "foo"}'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual


def test_numpy_nested_l1():
    input = {'foo': {'bar': {np.int64(123): 'foo'}}, 'age': 20}
    expected = '{"foo": {"bar": {"123": "foo"}}, "age": 20}'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual


def test_numpy_nested_l2():
    input = {'foo': {'bar': {'baz': {'foo': np.int64(123)}}}, 'age': 20}
    expected = '{"foo": {"bar": {"baz": {"foo": 123}}}, "age": 20}'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual


def test_array_int():
    input = [1, 2, 3]
    expected = '[1, 2, 3]'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual


def test_array_numpy_int():
    input = [np.int64(n) for n in [1, 2, 3]]
    expected = '[1, 2, 3]'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual


def test_array_numpy_float():
    input = [np.float64(n) for n in [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]]
    expected = '[1.1, 2.2, 3.3]'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual


def test_object_array():
    input = [{'foo': 'bar'}]
    expected = '[{"foo": "bar"}]'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual


def test_object_array_numpy():
    input = [{'foo': 'bar'}, {'bar': np.int64(123)}]
    expected = '[{"foo": "bar"}, {"bar": 123}]'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual


def test_tuple_value():
    input = {'foo': ('bar', 'baz')}
    expected = '{"foo": ["bar", "baz"]}'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual


def test_tuple_key():
    input = {('bar', 'baz'): 'foo'}
    expected = '{"[\\"bar\\", \\"baz\\"]": "foo"}'
    actual = stringify(input)
    assert expected == actual
```

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to *save*, just use pickle.

the API is almost the same.

```
import pickle
data = {('category1', 'category2'): 4}
s = pickle.dumps(data) # serialized data
d = pickle.loads(s) # the original dictionary
```

---

If you wanna save it into disk,

```
# write
with open('file1.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)

# read
with open('file1.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```